# File Upload returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am using **Express File Upload** and when I attempt to send a post request to it, it returns the error from the error-handler that is set up, which essentially it couldn't find any files when I `console.log(req.files)` it returns undefined, which is why the error is being sent back, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

**Index.js**

```
router.post('/upload-avatar', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.files)
    if(!req.files) {
      res.send({
        status: false,
        message: 'No file uploaded'
      });
    } else {
      //Use the name of the input field (i.e. "avatar") to retrieve the uploaded file
      let avatar = req.files.avatar;

      //Use the mv() method to place the file in upload directory (i.e. "uploads")
      avatar.mv('./uploads/' + avatar.name);

      //send response
      res.send({
        status: true,
        message: 'File is uploaded',
        data: {
          name: avatar.name,
          mimetype: avatar.mimetype,
          size: avatar.size
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

**App.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');


const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});



app.use(fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**I am using an azure server, and at the moment I am using postman to get it working first!**

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Try moving `app.use('/', indexRouter);` line just before the error handler middleware.

Comment: It just returned a 404 error saying that the page was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middlewares should be ordered appropriately. Your file upload middleware was placed below your index router. So when a request hits the server Express would run your indexRouter’s handler before the upload middleware and unless your handler calls `next()`, the file upload middleware would not process your request. And you cannot call `next()` since it would mean “I’m done with my part, hand this request (req) to the next middleware/handler”.

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');


const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```